# Cron periodically for different scripts

Tags: cron

I would like to run several scripts every half-hour. This obviously would work with this line

```
*/30 * * * * script.sh
```

My question now is how I would be able to run several of these at different times. As in, script.sh to run 5 minutes before script2.sh which then is 5 minutes before script3.sh. If that shouldn't be possible, any way to ensure that they aren't executed within 5 minutes of each other would suffice.

I did see solutions to do this with a script or otherwise programmatic. If cron can't be used for the job a "not possible" is what I'm looking for as the answer.

Comment: `*/30 * * * * script1.sh` `*/35 * * * * script2.sh` `*/40 * * * * script3.sh`?

Comment: That would not execute them equally often. Each should run every 30 minutes. It also would not guarantee that they won't run at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*/30` is equivalent to `0,30`. If you use the latter syntax you can simply use `5,35` for another job to offset it from the first.

For example, for three jobs you could do:

```
 0,30 * * * * script1.sh
 5,35 * * * * script2.sh
10,40 * * * * script3.sh
```

Note that if `script1.sh` takes longer than 5 minutes to run, there will still be overlap between `script1.sh` and `script2.sh`. If you really must avoid that, you should probably consider lock files (using e.g. `flock`).